# Can't make a css tooltip only with a

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have a problem making a css tooltip, I watched the tutorial on http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip but I didn't understand the css code.

What i did on my Javascript class, is create a new image and calling it `getSclass()` to apply the css. On the code that the tutorial provided, I didn't understand where I should put the html part, and how about the a.tooltip (does that mean that I have the give my image an special ID?)
What i have to do then if I should work only with a Javascript class (when I call the `img`) and a css file.
I also made a call for `settooltiptext()`, but I think it is not the case here!

Comment: Instead of explaining us what you did, you should share your code and maybe a working example.

Comment: I have fixed your question as good as possible, but it still makes no sense. Please read it through and make sure it's understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via CSS itself. Although there are lot of plugins, lets do something like this. First, you need a hovering element, say in this case, a link.

```
<a href="#">Hover Me!</a>
```

Next should be the tool tip. We can have a `<span>` for now and put it inside the link.

```
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a>
```

Now comes the real CSS part.

```css
a span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a {position: relative;}
a:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

**Snippet**

```css
a span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a {position: relative;}
a:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a>
```

This is just one of a pure CSS solution. You can see the working [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/acyNw/1/).

---

However, there are a lot of plugins, which keep this concept as base and work for hover-cards and tool tips. Some good examples include:

- [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)
- [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)
- [HoverCard](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard)
- [40+ Tooltips Scripts With AJAX, JavaScript & CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/)

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's a bit hard to guess just what you're working on and how you are outputting the html. But maybe helping you understand the css code will help you solve your issues.

The css tooltip depends on the following html structure

```
<!--the a element should wrap both the standard text or image-->
<a href="#" class="tooltip"> 
    <!--tooltip text or image here -->
    Tooltip
    <!--the tooltip part here-->
    <span>
        <!--important is the class callout on the image-->
        <img class="callout" src="cssttp/callout.gif" />
        <!-- and this is just text that fills the tooltip-->
        <strong>Most Light-weight Tooltip</strong><br />
         This is the easy-to-use Tooltip driven purely by CSS.
    </span>
</a>
```

The key css rules are the following:

```
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;
    display:none; /*hide the span normally*/
    padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}

a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; /*when we hover the tooltip, the span inside gets displayed inline*/
    position:absolute; /*and we make sure that the tooltip doesn't move other content*/
    color:#111;
    border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;
}
```

The rest of the css is just to style it 'pretty', but the main functionality lies in the 3 commented lines.

So when you output your code to html, you need to produce an 'a' element with class tooltip, inside of which you have text (or an image) and a span, and the span should have the image inside with class callout.

Hope this helps.